# XmlNode.InnerText

Tags: c#, .net, xml

We have XML like so:

```
<Example>
  <Node>Some text here
    <ChildNode>Child 1</ChildNode>
    <ChildNode>Child 2</ChildNode>
  </Node>
</Example>
```

We are using `XmlDocument` to parse this.

When we have the XmlNode of the "Node" element, `XmlNode.InnerText` returns us this:

```
"Some text hereChild 1Child2"
```

How can we get the inner text of the *Node* element without the child nodes' inner text?  We don't really want to use any RegEx or string splitting to accomplish this.

Note: We also don't want to switch to using a different set of classes to parse this XML, it would be too much of a code change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var text = doc.SelectSingleNode("Example/Node/text()").InnerText; // or .Value
```

returns

```
"Some text here\r\n    "
```

and `text.Trim()` returns

```
"Some text here"
```

Comment: Trying this: node.SelectSingleNode("text()").InnerText.Trim()

Comment: @Jonathan: Yea, that's the same, I just wanted to show you some inner process

Comment: @Jonathan: jfyi, you can use tildes to highlight code into a comment:`node.SelectSingleNode("text()").InnerText.Trim()`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
XmlDocument d=new XmlDocument();
d.LoadXml(@"<Example>
  <Node>Some text here
    <ChildNode>Child 1</ChildNode>
    <ChildNode>Child 2</ChildNode>
  </Node>
</Example>");
var textNodeValues=d.DocumentElement
    .FirstChild
    .ChildNodes
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Where(x=>x.NodeType==XmlNodeType.Text)
    .Select(x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault(x=>x.NodeType==XmlNodeType.Text)` is more suitable for this case, I guess. Isn't it?

Comment: @Abatishchev: To answer the question directly, you are right, but OP does not specify behaviour in the case that other text nodes exist. I prefer your Xpath anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement like:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<Example><Node>Some text here<ChildNode>Child 1</ChildNode><ChildNode>Child 2</ChildNode></Node></Example>");
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode( "Example/Node" );
    if (node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        string value = node.FirstChild.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no direct way to do that. You'll have to iterate over the child text nodes and build the concatenated text yourself:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

public string GetImmediateInnerText(XmlNode node)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes) {
        if (child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) {
            builder.Append(child.Value);
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

You can also use the `text()` XPath expression, as @abatishchev does:

```
public string GetImmediateInnerText(XmlNode node)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (XmlNode child in node.SelectNodes("text()")) {
        builder.Append(child.Value);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Indeed there is: `text()` XPath function

Comment: @abatishchev, true, but you need to use it with `SelectNodes()` instead of `SelectSingleNode()`, or you will only return the first child text node of the element :)

Comment: Yea, I tried and you're right. But I think it's really rare case when some text exists after child nodes. IMO text is existence _before_ child nodes is rare _too_. Also there is a workaround: `doc.SelectNodes("../text()").Cast<XmlNode>().Select(n=>n.InnerText.Trim())`, etc..

Comment: @abat: you need to check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75250/other-than-reformatting-code-should-you-substantially-alter-a-questions-code-sa