# get XML node ending in backslash value vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing

My current XML file has a structure similar to this:

```xml
<?xml>
  <Assessment xmlns="...">
    <Vehicle>
      <Model> model text </Model>
      <VersionName /> some text
    </Vehicle>
  </Assessment>
```

Note that `<VersionName>` node ends with backslash so I cannot find the way to get the data. Right now my code is:

```vb
m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
m_xmld.Load(ListBox1.Items.Item(i) & ".xml")
nsmgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("sd", "http://example.com")
m_nodelist = m_xmld.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/sd:Assessment/sd:Vehicle", nsmgr)

For Each m_node In m_nodelist
    Dim carModel = m_node.SelectSingleNode("sd:Model", nsmgr).InnerText
    Dim carVersion = m_node.SelectSingleNode("sd:VersionName", nsmgr).InnerText
    txtModel.Text = carModel
    txtCarVersion.Text = carVersion
Next
```

It worked just without `carVersion` lines.

Any idea?

Comment: The data is not in <VersionName>. The <VersionName> node closed with that backslash. Actually, the text is in the <Vehicle> node.

Comment: @djv so, to get the text near <VersionName> I should parse <Vehicle>?

Comment: Yes, it's in there. In your loop, `m_node` corresponds to <Vehicle>, and if it's always at the end as in your example, you can access it like this `m_node.LastChild.Value`

Comment: Your question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714962/xmlnode-innertext

Comment: Thank you, everything is clear now

Comment: / is a forwards slash, not a backslash. And it's not part of the XML "node" - nodes exist only in the output of the XML parser, not in its input.